# I can't decode gmail html message when i use imap (PHP)

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-imap, gmail-pop

Im a newebie developer, i use **imap with gmail** on my own **PHP application**.

The problem, when i try to **decode a gmail html message** (Specially google+/linkedin). It is displayed in an original (coded) format.
I want to display it in standard format as it is displayed on GMAIL.

For Example :

**Original Message on GMAIL :** 
[Image (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTPge.png)

**Message on my application :** 
[Image (Click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1bc1.png)

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

That looks like base64 encoding. So decode it!

`$hopefullyTheHtml = base64_decode($string);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: thank you for your reply , when i used base64_decode , the message is decoded to text format, it's good but i want to get html format.

Comment: When i use "imap_fetchstructure", it return Transfer encodings value = "4" that corresponds to "Quoted-Printable".
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php

"Quoted-Printable" work only for simple message, but does'nt work for message received from Google+ for example.